# HockeyApp Crash Analytics - App Store and Play Store

Tags: android, ios, hockeyapp

I had a quick question about HockeyApp and it looks very confusing about distribution.

If I prefer to integrate HockeyApp Analytics and distribute to the App Stores, will I see analytics and crash reports even though its not distributed using HockeyApp Distribution.

Comment: https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x-tvos/hockeyapp-for-ios#introduction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Analytics and Crash Reporting features of HockeyApp without distributing the app through HockeyApp. Everything can be used independently.